# Isomorphism between $\mathbb{C}^{n}$ and the Complexification of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$

Tags: linear-algebra, complete-spaces, vector-space-isomorphism

What is an easy way (without tensors) to show, that the complexification of the Euclidean space $\mathbb {R} ^{n}$ gives the unitary space $\mathbb {C} ^{n}$. Or more detailed: I'd like to show, that $\mathbb{C}^{n}$ is isomorphic to the complexification $\left(\mathbb{R}^{n}\right)_{\mathbb{C}}$ of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. I thought of it like this:
$\mathbb{R}^{n}$ has the base
$$
e_{j}=(0, \ldots, 0,1,0, \ldots, 0) \in \mathbb{R}^{n}, \quad j=1, \ldots, n .
$$
Since the $1$ at position $j$ is also a complex number, $e_{j}$ can likewise be regarded as an element of $\mathbb{C}^{n}$, so there is an isomorphism. Is this already an acceptable explanation?

---

Definition of Complexification without tensors:

Let $V$ be a vector space over the field of real numbers $\mathbb{R}$. The complexification of $V$ is the direct sum
$$
V_{\mathbb{C}}=V \oplus V=V \times V
$$
On the new space, the addition is componentwise
$$
(x, y)+\left(x^{\prime}, y^{\prime}\right)=\left(x+x^{\prime}, y+y^{\prime}\right)
$$
and the scalar multiplication with $\alpha+\beta i \in \mathbb{C}$ by
$$
(\alpha+\beta i)(x, y)=(\alpha x-\beta y, \beta x+\alpha y)
$$
is defined.
This makes $V_{\mathbb{C}}$ a vector space over the body of complex numbers $\mathbb{C}$.

In analogy to the notation of complex numbers, for the pair $(x, y) \in V_{\mathbb{C}}$ one also writes $x+iy$

Comment: Are you addressing the "Euclidean" and "unitary" issues you brought up? That is more subtle than taking the $\Bbb R$-basis to be a $\Bbb C$-basis.

Answer (score 1):

My rhetorical question to you is, what is your characterization (not "definition") of "complexification" of a real vector space, so that you know that your "construction/definition" gives the same thing as other versions?

A slightly fancy, but, I think, very illuminating, way to describe the complexification $CV$ of a real vector space $V$ is as an "adjoint functor" to the forgetful functor $\Phi$ that takes a complex vector space $W$ and "forgets" that it has *complex* scalar multiplication, but only "remembers" that it has *real* scalar multiplication. Then "complexification" $C$ is an adjoint functor in the sense that
$$
\mathrm{Hom}_\mathbb C(CV,W)\;\approx\; \mathrm{Hom}_\mathbb R(V,\Phi W)
$$
for every complex vector space $W$, *and* that the isomorphism is "natural" in a fairly reasonable sense, that real and complex vector space homs fit together with it.

As usual, this proves uniqueness up to unique isomorphism, if the thing exists at all. :)

The typical tensor product (or Hom) *construction* of complexification is proven to fulfill this characterization.

Presumably the tensor-product-less construction also can be proven to do so. :)

Still/and, "extension of scalars" (not just about real/complex, but far more generally) for free modules *also* can be proven to behave the way you indicate. For similarly very-general reasons. :)

Comment: "and that the isomorphism is 'natural' in a fairly reasonable sense, that real and complex vector space homs fit together with it" - Could you please explain what that means?

Comment: @Filippo, well, much more could be said here, but the idea is that $F$ is "natural" means that for a morphism of objects $f:X\to Y$, $F$ gives a morphism $F(f):F(X)\to F(Y)$, and so on. That just says that $F$ is a "functor". But/and the "naturality" of things is of that type, generally: all the diagrams that might commute _do_. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are familiar with adjoint functors and free vector spaces, this explanation will be easy. If not, it will be incomprehensible.

The complexification functor $C : \mathbb{R}-Vec \to \mathbb{C}-Vec$ is the left adjoint of the forgetful functor $U_3 : \mathbb{C}-Vec \to \mathbb{R}-Vec$.

Note that the free functors $F_1 : Set \to \mathbb{R}-Vec$ and $F_2 : Set \to \mathbb{C}-Vec$ are the left adjoints to the forgetful functors $U_1 : \mathbb{R}-Vec \to Set$ and $U_2 : \mathbb{C}-Vec \to Set$ respectively.

Now note that $U_1 \circ U_3 = U_2$. Therefore, taking left adjoints, we have $C \circ F_1 \cong F_2$. In other words, the free complex vector space over a set $S$ is the complexification of the free real vector space over the set $S$.

Now $\mathbb{R}^n$ is the free vector space on $n$ elements. Therefore, its complexification is the free complex vector space on $n$ elements - that is, $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: @Filippo Left adjoints are always unique up to unique isomorphism.

Comment: If there was some set $S$ with $\mathbb R^n=F_1(S)$ and $\mathbb C^n=F_2(S)$, then your answer would imply that $\mathbb C^n=C(\mathbb R^n)$. But we can not assume that, can we?

Comment: @Filippo You don’t need a strict equality here, just an isomorphism. Take any set $S$ with $n$ elements - then the free $k$-vector space on $S$ is isomorphic to $k^n$.

Comment: But the point is that the equality $\mathbb C^n=C(\mathbb R^n)$ does hold, doesn't it? Note that the OP asked for "a way to show that the complexification of $\mathbb R^n$ gives $\mathbb C^n$".